# How to skip and continue file load failures in Vertica?

Tags: vertica

I'm trying to load thousands of compressed files at once over NFS into Vertica with a copy statement with the glob expression, but the operation is aborting on the following error:

```
ERROR 6253:  Error occured during LZO header processing: expecting more than 8 bytes, possibly file corrupted
```

What's the right way to tell vertica to continue on loading all the good files and just report which ones failed at the end of the load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running Vertica 7.2.x, they added a new parameter called `ERROR TOLERANCE`. Prior to this version, it does not exist.

You can see the copy options [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/Parameters.htm?Highlight="ERROR%20TOLERANCE").

> Treats each source during execution independently when loading data.
>   The statement is not rolled back if a single source is invalid. The
>   invalid source is skipped and the load continues.
>
> This parameter is disabled for ORC files, Parquet files, and when
>   using a fenced User Defined Load (UDL).

The only other alternative would be to precheck the validity in a script or load them separately (obviously this would be a performance issue so I would opt for the precheck).

Comment: thanks, that was really fast.  It's a shame that this disables the apportioned loading capabilities, though.

Comment: @tamale You could fix this within the ApportionedLoad udx itself to catch and handle errors on sources. Not that this is trivial (unless you already happened to be versed in writing UDL).

Comment: @tamale Also, one note is that apportioned load is not necessary if your data is already split into many files and you reference them all with `on any node`.  It'll already parallel load each file on a different node.

Comment: @tamale also, as of 8.0 you can divide up a load yourself to gain some parallelism without apportioned load.  For example COPY ... FROM 'group1'* ON (node1, node2), 'group2*' ON (node3, node4) etc.  See https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/UsingParallelLoadStreams.htm.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yep that's what I was referring to, although I think it is true for older versions as well. +1 for doc ref :-)

Comment: @woot ON ANY NODE and ON node (single) have been there a whie; specifying a subset of nodes >1 is new. But the OP is using NFS, so presumably all data is available to all nodes and ON ANY NODE is the right approach.

Comment: @MonicaCellio True. Although not many cases I'd want to use it.   I do have one case where we have execute only nodes set up with a NAS, and we want to only load using those nodes.  In this case it would be pretty useful. Also, if for some reason your nas is only mounted on a subset of nodes.

Comment: I believe configurations with execute-only nodes were one of the motivations for the feature.